# Clicking an object only works sometimes (Unity 3D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Yo!

I have a very basic activation code where the player clicks an object and the object will do its thing. The problem is that sometimes it works on the first click, and something it works on the second, third or fourth click.

I suspect this has something to do with update frequencies but I have no idea what to do to get this work properly.

Here's the code I have:

```
void OnTriggerStay(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
            {
                if (Activated.GetComponent<raycastTest> ().SystemEnabled == true) 
                {
                    Activated.GetComponent<raycastTest> ().SystemEnabled = false;
                } 
                else if (Activated.GetComponent<raycastTest> ().SystemEnabled == false) 
                {
                    Activated.GetComponent<raycastTest> ().SystemEnabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OnTriggerStay is aligned with the FixedUpdate. If it is set to 60 (I think it is by default) but your computer runs 100fps then you have 40 frames that are discarded in the physics process.

But the Input runs with the OS, so you will have 100 checks for Input per second.

So by logic you have 40% chances to miss a hit.

If you press during one of those 40 discarded frame, since you check for button down, it is only valid for that frame. Next frame it is gone.

A solution would be to flag when you enter/exit and check that flag when you press:

```
bool isIn = false;
void OnTriggerEnter(Collision col)
{
     isIn = true;
}
void OnTriggerExit(Collision col)
{
     isIn = false;
}

void Update()
{
     if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && isIn == true){ Action();}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really simple, but genius solution!